# Diff between 2 versions in Contact Flow

Tags: amazon-connect

How to run a different between 2 versions of contact flow json? I don't think the order is maintained in the contact flows

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, as soon as you make a change the order changes. From a quick test it appears that the blocks that have been changed go to the bottom of the exported json. In WinMerge and a single block it was usable. But with multiple changes it will get less and less useful.

Note after exporting I had to run a json formatter, as teh exported json is on a single line.

Comedy answer: Take a screenshot of each flow then put them in different layers in a image editor and set one layer as an XOR of another. Just tried this and it worked suprisingly well. you can see where at least some differences are as long as the difference can be seen in a block without having to open it. Doesn't help if you have moved blocks around though :)